# OpenERP : Saving field value (amount) into an account

Tags: python, odoo, accounting

I'm new to OpenERP and python and I need some help saving an amount into a particular account.
I have created a field in the invoice form that calculates a specific amount based on some code and displays that amount in the field. What I want to do is to associate an account with this field, so when the invoice is validated and/or payed, this amount is saved into an account and later on I can see it in the journal entries and/or chart of account. Any idea how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override "pay_and_reconcile" function to write in account field, this function is called at time of Pay.

action_date_assign()

action_move_create()

action_number()

this 3 function are called at time of validating invoice. 
You can override any one from this or you can add your own function . in workflow for the "open" activity.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot, now at least I know where to look. I'll try to study the code and create mine.

Answer (score 1):

You should override the write method of the invoice. Have a look at other addons on how to do that (you can find a lot of example using

```
grep -r "def write" *
```

inside the addons' folder.